# Do 'exogenous' and 'exogenetic' mean the same thing?

Tags: adjectives, suffixes

IMF managing director Kristalina Georgieva used a word I had never heard before when she stated, of the UK :

> The announced fiscal plan navigates well the difficult tradeoff between fighting inflation and protecting household incomes in a recession primarily caused by the **exogenous** energy price shock.

[MSN.com IMF Warning to UK - 12th January 2023](https://www.msn.com/en-gb/money/other/imf-warns-that-uk-faces-sobering-economic-outlook/ar-AA16gbHZ?ocid=mailsignout&pc=U591&cvid=81f246f8c148436d9d118d22d0b27b55)

Used in botany, the word would describe an 'exogen', a form of life existing outside of an established body, an additional and exterior growth, [see OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/66316?redirectedFrom=exogenous#eid)

Used in geology, and especially of volcanoes, the word expresses rock formation outside of the crater, extraneous protrusions. Here, the OED refers to the word 'exogenetic', as though they are either related or equivalent.

Is it usual for adjectives to exist in two forms, the '-ous' form and the '-ic' form ? Or is there a subtle difference in shade of meaning between the two ?

Comment: The word *exogenous* is common in economics; I've never heard or seen *exogenetic* used is economics, so while obviously related, one or the other may be characteristic of particular scientific disciplines.

Comment: [***ANSWER REDACTED***]

Answer (score 1):

Essentially yes, but it depends on use case and tense: here;

Exogenous: as a result of external forces
https://www.etymonline.com/word/exogenous

Exogenetic would be the factors that do exist outside
https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/exogenetic